# Create a dictionary from output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary from the following output text file,

```
GigabitEthernet1/4 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/5 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/6 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/9 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/10 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/11 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/32 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/35 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 1000 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/36 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 1000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/47 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
```

Something like this `{'GigabitEthernet':'2/47', 'input rate':'0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'}`
Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task.

For example:

```
txt = '''GigabitEthernet1/4 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/5 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/6 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/9 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/10 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet1/11 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/32 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/35 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 1000 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/36 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 1000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec
GigabitEthernet2/47 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec'''

import re

out = [{'GigabitEthernet': a, 'input rate': b, 'output rate': c} for a, b, c in re.findall(r'GigabitEthernet(.*?)\s.*?(\d+ bits/sec).*?(\d+ bits/sec)', txt)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=120)
```

Prints:

```
[{'GigabitEthernet': '1/4', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '1/5', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '1/6', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '1/9', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '1/10', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '1/11', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '2/32', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '2/35', 'input rate': '1000 bits/sec', 'output rate': '1000 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '2/36', 'input rate': '1000 bits/sec', 'output rate': '1000 bits/sec'},
 {'GigabitEthernet': '2/47', 'input rate': '0 bits/sec', 'output rate': '0 bits/sec'}]
```